# the difference between the Calling Object and the Target Object?

Tags: spring-aop

I'm learning Spring AOP and there are some termonolgies of this concept like Advice , PointCut , JoinPoint .. One of them is AOP Proxy and I found that a proxy is an intermediary object, introduced by the AOP framework, between the calling object and the target object. So my question is what is the difference between the Calling Object and the Target Object ?

Answer (score -1):

Plese go through the reference document section : [Understanding AOP Proxies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7pr4.png)

Following image depicts the concept of a proxy.

[image]

Consider a class `TestService` with method `run()` and a class `Pojo` with method `foo()`. Also consider Spring framework creates a proxy for `Pojo` .

```
@Component
public class TestService{

  @Autowired  
  Pojo pojo;

  public void run(){
     pojo.foo()
  }

}
```

Here the instance of `TestService` is the Calling Object and instance of `Pojo` is the Target object.